# Windws Phone 8 Dynamicly create something

Tags: windows-phone-8

I want to create a timetable App for Windows Phone 8.
And I have a Problem.

There is an Form where the user can add subjects or Tasks:

[Screenshot http://img96.imageshack.us/img96/6932/unbenannt1ku.png](http://img96.imageshack.us/img96/6932/unbenannt1ku.png)

If the user klicks on "hinzufügen" = add, I want to create something like this:

[Screenshot http://img23.imageshack.us/img23/7262/unbenanntsjcd.png](http://img23.imageshack.us/img23/7262/unbenanntsjcd.png)

Edit:

I want to create this greeen box and the Time in front of it on runtime of the application , if I klick on the Button "hinzufügen" = add.

The user enters the WeekDay Subject, Room, beginning time and the ending time of the lesson.

And with this Data I want to create this greenbox with WeekDay,Subject,Room in it + beginning time and the ending time of the lesson in front of it.

I hope you understand me sorry for my bad english

I really dont know how to do this, I tried it with an Wrappanel and textboxes, but it but it did not work.

Ps: This is my first Windows Phone 8 App

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it working but now I´m facing another Problem:

First I create a Canvas:

```
private void AddItem()
    {
        Canvas myCanvas = new Canvas();
        Canvas myCanvas2 = new Canvas();
        myCanvas2.Height = 128;
        myCanvas2.Width = 104;
        myCanvas.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
        myCanvas.Height = 200;
        myCanvas.Width = 350;
        myCanvas2.Margin = new System.Windows.Thickness(5,10,0,0);
        myCanvas.Margin = new System.Windows.Thickness(66, 10, 0, 0);
```

Then I create three Textblocks:

First: Add a TextBlock to first Canvas:

```
TextBlock TextBlock1= new TextBlock();
    TextBlock1.FontSize = 48;
    TextBlock1.Text = Fach.Text;
    Canvas.SetTop(TextBlock1, 10);
    Canvas.SetLeft(TextBlock1, 29);
    myCanvas.Children.Add(TextBlock1);
```

Second: Add a second TextBlock to first Canvas:

```
TextBlock TextBlock2= new TextBlock();
    TextBlock2.FontSize = 24;
    TextBlock2.Text = Raum.Text;
    Canvas.SetTop(TextBlock2, 79);
    Canvas.SetLeft(TextBlock2, 31);
    myCanvas.Children.Add(TextBlock2);
```

Third: Add a second TextBlock to second Canvas:

```
TextBlock TextBlock3 = new TextBlock();
    TextBlock3.FontSize = 20;
    TextBlock3.Text = Zeit;
    Canvas.SetTop(TextBlock3, 36);
    Canvas.SetLeft(TextBlock3, 10);
    myCanvas2.Children.Add(TextBlock3);
```

Add myCanvas and myCanvas2 to wrappanel:

```
wrapPanel.Children.Add(myCanvas);
    wrapPanel.Children.Add(myCanvas2);
    }
    };
```

The first Canvas(myCanvas) is showing up(The box) but the second Canvas(myCanvas2) is not showing up(the time). Somone know why? Because of the wappanel?

Answer (score 0):

as i understand you what you need is to switch from one pivot item to another when you click on abutton and this can done by following :

suppose that your pivot name is  : myPivot
and your target pivot item is : second

you can attach this handler with this method :

```
    private void toNextPivot_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        myPivot.SelectedItem = second;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you but this is not what I want to do. I want to create this greeen box and the Time if I klick on the Button "hinzufügen" = add. I Know how to add things to other pivot Items

Comment: The user enters the WeekDay Subject, Room, beginning time and the ending time of the lesson. And with this Data I want to create this greenbox with WeekDay,Subject,Room in it +  beginning time and the ending time of the lesson in front of it. I hope you understand me sorry for my bad english